# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I want to scrape the country names and country capitals from this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order

From the html code, I'm looking for all of these:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order"

html = requests.get(BASE_URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
countries = soup.find_all("td")

print (countries)
```

But I don't know how to actually get what's in between the  tags, especially since there are ones with no information in them.

I feel like it's pretty simple but I can't really understand all the tutorials since they use classes and this wiki page doesn't have classes for its info inside the table.

Comment: You can use any valid identifying trait to select something for extraction.  Perhaps you should update your question with a brief analysis of the page you are attempting to manipulate.  Some common but brittle approaches are "find the third table on the page" or "find the table after the first subsection headline" but perhaps you can come up with something more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some code to iterate over the table columns as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order"

capitals_countries = []

html = requests.get(BASE_URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
country_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "wikitable sortable"})

for row in country_table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')

    if len(cols) == 3:
        capitals_countries.append((cols[0].text.strip(), cols[1].text.strip()))

for capital, country in capitals_countries:
    print('{:35} {}'.format(capital, country))
```

This would display the capital and country pairs starting as follows:

```
Abu Dhabi                           United Arab Emirates
Abuja                               Nigeria
Accra                               Ghana
Adamstown                           Pitcairn Islands
Addis Ababa                         Ethiopia
Algiers                             Algeria
Alofi                               Niue
Amman                               Jordan
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
>>> table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})  # find the table
>>> tds = table.find_all('td')   # get all the table data
>>> countries = [tds[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(tds), 3)]  # get all the countries' data
>>> result = [[item.text for item in country] for country in countries]  # get the final result
>>> print ' /'.join(result[0])
Abu Dhabi / United Arab Emirates /
```