# Scraping table data with BeautifulSoup or Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm somewhat new to using python and I've been given a task that requires data scraping from a table. I do not know very much html either. I've never done this before and have spent a couple days looking at various ways to scrape tables. Unfortunately all of the examples are of what appears to be a more simple webpage layout than what I'm dealing with. I've tried quite a few various methods, but none of them allow me to select the table data that I need.

How would one scrape the table at the bottom of the following webpage under the "Daily Water Level" tab?

url = https://apps.wrd.state.or.us/apps/gw/gw_info/gw_hydrograph/Hydrograph.aspx?gw_logid=HARN0052657

I've tried using the methods in the following links and others not show here:

[Beautiful Soup Scraping table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703694/beautiful-soup-scraping-table)

[Scrape table with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584154/scrape-table-with-beautifulsoup)

[Web scraping with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820066/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup)

Some of the script I've tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("table")  # {"class": "xxxx"})
```

I've also tried using pandas, but I can't figure out how to select the table I need instead of the first table on the webpage that has the basic well information:

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.read_html(url)
df_list
```

Unfortunately the data I need doesn't even show up when I run this script and the table I'm trying to select doesn't have a class that I can use to select only that table and not the table of basic well information.  I've inspected the webpage, but can't seem to find a way to get to the correct table.

As far as the final result would look, I would need to export it as a csv or as a pandas data frame so that I can then graph it with modeled groundwater data for comparison purposes. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would not scrape this, I would look for a source database

Comment: Do you want to scrap only Daily Water Level Tab ?

Comment: @anon01 while your comment is not all that helpful, it does confirm how I was feeling about this task and honestly made me feel better as to why I was struggling making any progress, haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach using python - [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the API URL and do a GET request with the dynamic parameters(in CAPS) you can change the value of Well No, Start and end date to get the desired result.
2. After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
3. It will iterate all over the list of daily water level data and create a list of all the data points so that it can be used to create a CSV file  for ex:- GW Login Id, GW Site ID, Land Surface Elevation, Record date etc.
4. Finally it will write all the headers and data in the CSV file. (! Important please make sure to input the file path in the **file_path** variable)

   ```
    import json
    import requests
    from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    import csv

    def scrap_daily_water_level():

    file_path = '' #Input File path here
    file_name = 'daily_water_level_data.csv' #File name

    #CSV headers
    csv_headers = ['Line #','GW Log Id','GW Site Id', 'Land Surface Elevation', 'Record Date','Restrict to OWRD only', 'Reviewed Status', 'Reviewed Status Description', 'Water level ft above mean sea level', 'Water level ft below land surface'] 
    list_of_water_readings = []

    #Dynamic Params
    WELL_NO = 'HARN0052657'
    START_DATE = '1/1/1905'
    END_DATE = '12/30/2050'

    #API URL
    URL = 'https://apps.wrd.state.or.us/apps/gw/gw_data_rws/api/' + WELL_NO + '/gw_recorder_water_level_daily_mean_public/?start_date=' + START_DATE + '&end_date=' + END_DATE + '&reviewed_status=&restrict_to_owrd_only=n'

    response = requests.get(URL,verify=False) #GET API call
    json_result = json.loads(response.text) #JSON loads to parse JSON data

    print('Daily water level data count ',json_result['feature_count']) # Prints no. of data counts
    extracted_data = json_result['feature_list'] #Extracted data in JSON form

    for idx, item in enumerate(extracted_data): #Iterate over the list of extracted data
        list_of_water_readings.append({ #append and create list of data with headers for further usage
                                    'Line #': idx + 1, 
                                    'GW Log Id' : item['gw_logid'],
                                    'GW Site Id': item['gw_site_id'],
                                    'Land Surface Elevation': item['land_surface_elevation'], 
                                    'Record Date': item['record_date'],
                                    'Restrict to OWRD only': item['restrict_to_owrd_only'],
                                    'Reviewed Status':item['reviewed_status'],
                                    'Reviewed Status Description': item['reviewed_status_description'],
                                    'Water level ft above mean sea level': item['waterlevel_ft_above_mean_sea_level'],
                                    'Water level ft below land surface': item['waterlevel_ft_below_land_surface']
                                    })
    #Create CSV and write data in to it.
    with open(file_path + file_name ,'a+') as daily_water_level_data_CSV: #Open file in a+ mode 
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(daily_water_level_data_CSV, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=csv_headers)
        print('Writing CSV header now...')
        csvwriter.writeheader() #Write headers in CSV file
        for item in list_of_water_readings: #iterate over the appended data and save them in to the CSV file.
            print('Writing data rows now..')
            print(item)            
            csvwriter.writerow(item)

    scrap_daily_water_level()
   ```

Comment: Hi @Vin, thank you for this taking the time for providing this in depth answer!!! No wonder why I was having a difficult time making any progress. Everything works as expected. I also really like how you added in variables that will allow me to select other wells to extract similar data by just changing the GW log ID. Brilliant! One quick question, what's the best way to approach reformatting the date column so that it does not include the time stamp (2017-08-04T00:00:00)?